# How to create intersection shader that simulates squishing?

Tags: unity, shaders, transparency, unity-shader-graph

I want to create a shader that will make spheres/circles look like a blob when colliding.

I don't understand shadergraph at all, but I tried to follow intersection shader tutorials.

The problem is that no one does intersection with another object with the same shader.
Also I want the spheres to be transparent.

I tried calculating vertices to achieve the same effect, but it's a total overkill. I know it should be possible with a shader.

How can I achieve this effect?

[image]

Comment: By default, each triangle being drawn has no knowledge of any other triangle or object in the scene. If you have a limited number of nearby spheres creating these "squish" planes, you could pass in their positions and radii as per-instance material properties. If not, you may have to investigate ways to approximate this with screen-space tricks.

Comment: You can achieve that effect by using ray marching and signed distance fields. Not sure whether that would be a worthwhile cost for your use case... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cp5WWtMoeKg